# Trying to open shortcut in Programs Menu folder throwing exception

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, advertised-shortcut

I tried the above solution,but unfortunately there is no difference in behaviour.So kindly suggest how to proceed further.

Regards,
Ranjan VijayKumar.

Comment: You need to update the post with the actual **Wix XML code** for the shortcut creation. My guess is you have set some **faulty parameters as a command line parameter by accident**.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a crash of some kind, not a WiX issue. If the install didn't fail, then you just have a crashing app. Tell someone what the exception is, the actual error message. Add some debugging to your program and perhaps try/catch exception handling and tracing to see how far it gets and where it crashes. For debug purposes, have it show a message box as the first thing it does so you can see that it loads and has no missing dependencies. Verify in your code that the things you are doing are actually working etc. I'm guessing it's been voted down most likely because it's not a WiX question at all - it's just your code crashing or a missing dependency for which have supplied no data at all.

Answer (score 0):

See the [**Wix samples**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut.html) for how to create a shortcut the proper way.

A couple of more links:

- [Wix Toolset Manual Table of Contents](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/)
- [How To: Files, Shortcuts and Registry](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/)